# How to Order a Drop-Down Menu, but Randomize Within It?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing

How can I change this:

```html
  def index
    @values = Value.all
  end
```

... to something that will put my drop down menu categories in this **order on the index**:

1) Mantra, 2) Quote,  3) Principle, 4) Other

BUT within each category the Value would be randomized, for example Mantra will show up first in the index but within the mantra category the mantras you typed in will have their order **randomized upon each page reload**.

**value.rb**

```html
class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user

 VALUES = ['Mantra', 'Quote', 'Principle', 'Other']

end
```

**values_controller.rb**

```html
class ValuesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_value, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @values = Value.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @value = current_user.values.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @value = current_user.values.build(value_params)
    if @value.save
      redirect_to @value, notice: 'Value was successfully created'
    else
      render action: 'new'
  end
end

  def update
    if @value.update(value_params)
      redirect_to @value, notice: 'Value was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @value.destroy
    redirect_to values_url
  end

  private
    def set_value
      @value = Value.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @value = current_user.values.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to values_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this value" if @value.nil?
    end

    def value_params
      params.require(:value).permit(:name, :categories)
    end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```html
<div id="values" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @values.each do |value| %>
        <%= value.name %><br/>
        <% if value.user == current_user %>
          <div class="actions">
            <%= link_to edit_value_path(value) do %>
            <b><%= value.categories %></b>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to value, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "category"? What do your `Value`s look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:** 
order the `@values` in a custom order:

1) Mantra, 2) Quote, 3) Principle, 4) Other

I'm assuming these labels come from the `name` attribute of your `Value` model. To get this non alphabetic custom ordering, and not having to rely on the `created_at` field for the ordering, you need a different attribute to sort on. I'd add a `sort:integer` attribute to `Value` and update the records with values for the `sort` field:

```
Value: name: "Mantra", sort: 0
Value: name: "Quote", sort: 1
Value: name: "Principle", sort: 2
Value: name: "Other", sort: 3
```

Then change your query to:

```
@values = Value.order :sort
```

That will get you the ordering you specified. Now, for your next problem. I'm assuming you have some association on this `Value` model. You mentioned:

> BUT within each category

So each `Value` instance is a category? If you have other models that `belong_to` a category, you would have a separate query that you would do the ordering on:

```
# index action
@categories = Category.order :sort

# then user clicks on a category and they go to its
# show action
@category = Category.find params[:id]
@items = @category.items.order 'RANDOM()'
```

So with the above, at your category index page would see the categories sorted by your custom ordering then, upon clicking on a category (e.g Mantra) to navigate to its show action they'd see items of the Mantra category in a random order on each page load.

Comment: I'm having a hard time with your code. Where do I put sort:integer - Controller, Model, index? Then where do I put the Value: name: block? And the query is the def index in the controller.

Comment: sort:integer is referring to a migration where you would add that field to your model